# DataGrid and ScrollBar styling WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm creating `DataGrid` style in WPF. Now I have rounded corners in my `DataGrid`, but when appears `ScrollBar`, it looks not beautiful. `DataGridHeader` corner is still rounded, and I can see space between corners of ScrollBar button and DataGridHeader. Here is an image:

[image]

I need to show rounded corners only when `DataGrid` **hasn't** `ScrollBar`.In all other cases I need to show this:

[image]

So how to remove dynamicaly that space on the first image?

Answer (score 0):

Style Scrollbar so that it overlaps the the grid by using negative left margin value